# Django Database Design With Intermediate Table- How With This Instance?

Tags: database, django, database-design, relational-database

Using Django, I am creating a database that will keep track of unanswered posts in forum and if/what employee(operator) is assigned to that post.

Models `Operator` and `ThreadVault` are permanent while `Thread` is intermediate/temp.

I will be making a api call to the forums to get a list of the unanswered posts once every ten minutes. I will then check to see if the `thread ID` already exists in the model `ThreadVault`. If not, it will add it to `ThreadVault`. Then, I will have a temporary/intermediate table `Thread` that will contain the unanswered posts for the past 10 minutes. After every 10 minutes, the table `Thread` will clear out and refresh with a new batch of unanswered threads.

A operator/employee may or may not be assigned to the thread. To do this, I am having `ThreadVault` `operator_user_name` point to `Operator` model.

```
class Operator:
    operator_ldap = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
            related_name='operator_requester')
    operator_irc_name = models.CharField(max_length="25")
    operator_user_name = models.CharField(max_length="25")

class ThreadVault:
    thread_id = models.CharField(max_length="50")
    url = models.CharField(max_length="200")
    operator_user_name = models.ForeignKey(Operator) ## Can be Empty

#intermediate table 
#Thread model clears out once every 
#10 minutes when API repopulates data
class Thread:
    url = models.ForeignKey(ThreadVault)
    author_username = models.CharField(max_length="50")
    author_name = models.CharField(max_length="50")
    thread_id = models.ForeignKey(ThreadVault)
    forum_id = models.CharField(max_length="50")
    subject = models.CharField(max_length="200")
    reply_count = models.CharField(max_length=("3"))
    latest_post_date = models.CharField(max_length=("50"))
    operator_user_name = models.ForeignKey(ThreadVault) ## Can be Empty
```

I know at this point I am not doing this correctly. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked out perfect:

```
class Operator(models.Model):
    operator_ldap = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
            related_name='operator_requester')
    operator_irc_name = models.CharField(max_length="25",
            blank=True, null=True)
    operator_user_name = models.CharField(max_length="25",
            blank=True, null=True)

class ThreadVault(models.Model):
    thread_id = models.CharField(max_length="50")
    url = models.CharField(max_length="200")
    operator_user_name = models.ForeignKey(Operator, blank=True, null=True) ## Can be Empty

#intermediate table 
#Thread model clears out once every 
#10 minutes when API repopulates data
class Thread(models.Model):
    url = models.ForeignKey(ThreadVault,
            related_name="url_vault")
    author_username = models.CharField(max_length="50")
    author_name = models.CharField(max_length="50")
    thread_id = models.ForeignKey(ThreadVault,
            related_name="thread_vault")
    forum_id = models.CharField(max_length="50")
    subject = models.CharField(max_length="200")
    reply_count = models.CharField(max_length=("3"))
    latest_post_date = models.CharField(max_length=("50"))
    operator_user_name = models.ForeignKey(ThreadVault, 
            related_name="operator_user_name_vault", 
            blank=True, null=True) ## Can be Empty
```